# Deploy application to localhost using Capistrano

Tags: capistrano

can somebody paste me "deploy.rb" file with configuration for LOCAL MACHINE ?

Whenever i try to use `cap local deploy` i get `onnection failed for: localhost (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))`

Configuration:

```
set :branch, "master"
set :deploy_to, "path/#{application}"

set :domain, "localhost"
role :app, domain
role :web, domain
role :db, domain, :primary => true
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anwser is very simple... SSH Agent was not enabled.